# POST Card displaying error

Tags: cpu, hardware, bios

The problem is : my computer start, and my screen is black (as always when there is a big problem :D).
I already tried to : change my motherboard, change my graphic card, change my power supply, reset CMOS : no success. Would it be the CPU ? :D :D :D ... :'(.

I'll tell you all I know when the problem occurred.
- "I was chilly peacefully playing a game when my PC instantly switched off. I opened my PC and I've seen a lot of dust in the alimentation fan. I vacuumed it!".

I recently bought a POST card that, they say : "give information about the POST checks".
This card, when I power up my computer after a long time, shows : --AA (4-digits screen).
When I switch off my computer and switch it on just after, the card shows : --FF.

I noticed the sound of the CPU fan is different between the AA and the FF code. (so the fans run).

From what does this error come from and how to solve the problem ?

Thank you for your time ! Have a great day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't tried to replace your memory...
As you can see a check point, I believe the CPU is still good.
Good luck.

Comment: I replaced my memory too. I have to tell too that I got a motherboard MSI 870A G54 that got 4 leds near the CPU labeled with "Power Phase 1, Power Phase 2, Power Phase 3, Power Phase 4". And the Power Phase 3 wasn't activated meanwhile the others were.

And I find nothing on Internet to give me the meaning of these leds.

Comment: Can't help you. I think you got a HW problem, not a BIOS problem. The meaning of the led is defined by motherboard vendor...You'd better call MSI for help.

Comment: Thank you, what means HW ? I'll call MSI =)

Answer (score 0):

To know what AA and FF mean, you need to get a list of POST codes for your system. Check with your motherboard manufacturer, perhaps in the manual.

If you can't find it there, the next best thing would be to get a list of generic POST codes for the BIOS. You will need to determine what BIOS is actually in use on the mobo though (AMI Aptio, Phoenix SecureCore Tiano, etc).  Then do a Google search for the BIOS name + POST codes, and you will pull up a list.

Note that just the code by itself may not be enough to debug it. The BIOS spits out hundreds of POST codes during boot up. The sequence of the codes can tell you something too.

Comment: Thank you, what's strange is that there're not several codes displaying : just one (I start the computer, and one code in shown) !

Comment: That would imply the computer isn't coming out of reset OK. Maybe a power problem or other major physical fault.